# "any" keyword not being recognized in javascript unit test

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery

```
let x= {
  y: {
    z: any
  }
};
```

'any' keyword isn't being recognized. The error says that the symbol 'any' is located in an inaccessible module. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote the code it means that you assign to variable `x` an object. I guess you want to declare a variable with a structure and you can do that this way:

```
let x: {
  y: {
    z: any
  }
};
```

Please note the colon (`:`) after `x` variable.

To make it more clear:

```
// let variable : structure = value;

// The following code is OK
let x: {
  y: {
    z: any
  }
} = { 
  y: {
      z: "test"
  }
};

// The following code throws an error:

let x: {
  y: {
    z: any
  }
} = { 
  y: {
      z: "test"
  },
  notDefined : {}
};
```

[[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%20%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20y%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20z%3A%20any%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%09%20%20y%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%20%20z%3A%20%22test%22%0D%0A%09%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%09%20%20notDefined%20%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09)]